# new/create edit/update controller actions with tricky model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, crud

I have a rails app with a bit tricky model as you see. App is able to create tasks for a given user.

I'm using the controller/form below. Obviously when I create task for sby I have to fill the :executor field since I'm gonna be the :assigner by default. Once the task is created, it's gonna be an :assigned_task from my point of view. 
The form below works perfectly for the new/create action and edit.html.erb gets displayed as well with the right parameters, but I get the error (even if I try to change an assigned_task not an executed_task): "No route matches [PATCH] "/users/1/tasks"" when it comes to the update action.

I'm not sure if it's my form or controller that goes wrong. If I hit $rake routes everything looks fine.

I got 2 questions: 1. How can I make the update action work for :assigned_tasks, so :assigner could edit the tasks they assigned to sby? 2. This is the harder question: What should I do to have :executors be able to edit as well the tasks they got assigned to (:executed_tasks)?

task model:

```
belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"
```

user model:

```
has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assigner_id"
has_many :executed_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "executor_id"
```

Form for new and edit:

```
<%= form_for @task, url: user_tasks_path do |f| %>
```

Controller:

```
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    if @task.save
      flash[:success] = "Task saved!"
      redirect_to user_tasks_path(current_user)
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = current_user
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    @task = @user.task.find(params[:id])
    if @task.update_attributes(task_params)
      flash[:success] = "Task updated!"
      redirect_to user_tasks_path(current_user)
    else
      render action: :edit
    end
  end

private

   def task_params
     params.require(:task).permit(:executor_id, :name, :content, :deadline).merge(assigner_id: current_user.id)
   end
```

routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                     Controller#Action
         static_pages_home GET    /static_pages/home(.:format)                    static_pages#home
        static_pages_about GET    /about(.:format)                                static_pages#about
         static_pages_help GET    /help(.:format)                                 static_pages#help
static_pages_privacypolicy GET    /privacypolicy(.:format)                        static_pages#privacypolicy
                  contacts GET    /contacts(.:format)                             contacts#index
                           POST   /contacts(.:format)                             contacts#create
               new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)                         contacts#new
              edit_contact GET    /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)                    contacts#edit
                   contact GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)                         contacts#show
                           PATCH  /contacts/:id(.:format)                         contacts#update
                           PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)                         contacts#update
                           DELETE /contacts/:id(.:format)                         contacts#destroy
          new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                        devise/sessions#new
              user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                        devise/sessions#create
      destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                       devise/sessions#destroy
             user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#create
         new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                   devise/passwords#new
        edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                  devise/passwords#edit
                           PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#update
                           PUT    /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#update
  cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                         devise/registrations#cancel
         user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                devise/registrations#create
     new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                        devise/registrations#new
    edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                           devise/registrations#edit
                           PATCH  /users(.:format)                                devise/registrations#update
                           PUT    /users(.:format)                                devise/registrations#update
                           DELETE /users(.:format)                                devise/registrations#destroy
         user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)                   devise/confirmations#create
     new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)               devise/confirmations#new
                           GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)                   devise/confirmations#show
              user_profile POST   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)               profiles#create
          new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)           profiles#new
         edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format)          profiles#edit
                           GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)               profiles#show
                           PATCH  /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)               profiles#update
                           PUT    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)               profiles#update
                           DELETE /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)               profiles#destroy
        complete_user_task PATCH  /users/:user_id/tasks/:id/complete(.:format)    tasks#complete
      uncomplete_user_task PATCH  /users/:user_id/tasks/:id/uncomplete(.:format)  tasks#uncomplete
 incoming_tasks_user_tasks GET    /users/:user_id/tasks/incoming_tasks(.:format)  tasks#incoming_tasks
 outgoing_tasks_user_tasks GET    /users/:user_id/tasks/outgoing_tasks(.:format)  tasks#outgoing_tasks
completed_tasks_user_tasks GET    /users/:user_id/tasks/completed_tasks(.:format) tasks#completed_tasks
                user_tasks GET    /users/:user_id/tasks(.:format)                 tasks#index
                           POST   /users/:user_id/tasks(.:format)                 tasks#create
             new_user_task GET    /users/:user_id/tasks/new(.:format)             tasks#new
            edit_user_task GET    /users/:user_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format)        tasks#edit
                 user_task GET    /users/:user_id/tasks/:id(.:format)             tasks#show
                           PATCH  /users/:user_id/tasks/:id(.:format)             tasks#update
                           PUT    /users/:user_id/tasks/:id(.:format)             tasks#update
                           DELETE /users/:user_id/tasks/:id(.:format)             tasks#destroy
                     users GET    /users(.:format)                                users#index
                           POST   /users(.:format)                                users#create
                  new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                            users#new
                 edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                       users#edit
                      user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                            users#show
                           PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                            users#update
                           PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                            users#update
                           DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                            users#destroy
                      root GET    /                                               static_pages#home
```

Comment: `<%= form_for @task, url: user_tasks_path do |f| %>` isn't right for update.  Try `<%= form_for @task do |f| %>` if you want to use it for both create and update.

Comment: I'd make two controllers - an assigned_tasks controller and an executed_tasks controller.  Then you can limit access based on the user's role correctly.

Comment: If I use the form without the url then it won't even load the edit.html.erb view.

Comment: Why is that?  The form_for method will figure out the url and method based on the object.  If it's not doing that correctly, there's something else going on with the instance variable.

Comment: Posted my routes. I don't exactly get why this one is having a path: user_profile POST   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format) profiles#create UNLIKE this one: POST   /users/:user_id/tasks(.:format) tasks#create

Answer (score 0):

I pulled it off. I still don't get why the previous one didn't work out and why this does. I used it for user.profile. It's true though that the profile  was  in one_to_one relationship with the user.

controller:

```
def edit
  @user = current_user
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @user = current_user
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  if @task.update_attributes(task_params)
    flash[:success] = "Task updated!"
    redirect_to user_tasks_path(current_user)
  else
    render action: :edit
  end
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for ([@user, @task]) do |f| %>
```